# Verifying that method was invoked using Mockito/PowerMock

Tags: mockito, powermock

I have task to cover by unit tests complex class, which interacts with some API.

Below is simplified structure of a part of this class.

All I need to do is to verify that inside testMethod() happenings invoking of print() method with correct variable.

Class 1:

```
public abstract class Class1 {

   public static Class2 class2;

   public void init() {
       //here initializes class2 variable, but for testing with mocks it doesn't needed
   }

   public void testMethod(String str) {
       class2.print(str);
   }
}
```

Class 2:

```
public class Class2 {

    public void print(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }

}
```

Here is the solution how I understand it:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FirstTest {

   @Test
   public void test() {
      Class1 class1 = Mockito.spy(Class1.class);
      Class2 class2 = Mockito.mock(Class2.class);
      doNothing().when(class2).print(anyString());
      Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(class1).testMethod("abc");
      verify(class2).print("abc");
    }
}
```

It returns such exception:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
class2.print("abc");
-> at FirstTest.test(FirstTest.java:50)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Wanted but not invoked:
class2.print("abc");
-> at FirstTest.test(FirstTest.java:50) 
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

at FirstTest.test(FirstTest.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Sure I have some big gap in knowledge of Mockito framework.
Maybe someone would write correct solution.

Eddited code:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

public class FirstTest {

```
@InjectMocks
Class1 class1 = Mockito.spy(Class1.class);

@Mock
Class2 class2;

@Test
public void test() {
    doNothing().when(class2).print("abc");
    class1.testMethod("abc");
    verify(class2).print(anyString());
}
}
```

Comment: You never call your testMethod(). You never initialize Class1.class2. And you don't need to spy on Class1. Just use new to create an instance.

Comment: No, testMethod() is called, I just renamed it for clarity when wrote question in one place and forgot to rename it in another. Already corrected. I can't use new, this class Class1 is abstract. And moreover I have condition not to mock this abstract class, so instead I have only spy method how I understand. Class2 also don't have constructor in original code and can't be initialized by new. I have to test it exactly with that structure of classes.

Comment: It's not called. You're just telling the spy what to do when the method is called (i.e. you're stubbing the method). That's unnecessary by the way, since the default behavior of a spy is to call the real method.

Comment: Thanks for remark about stubbing. Works with code above and class2 variable non-static. Only left to solve how to make it work with static variable.

Comment: As already said, your original code never sets Class1.class2.